# CSS attribute "overflow: scroll" cannot display scroll bar in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

[This is displayed in IE 11, UI does not display scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQhQu.png)

[This is displayed in chrome, UI display scroll bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EA0y.png)

The CSS code is the followed:

```
.r-listbox {  
            overflow:scroll;
            width: 200px;
            display: table-cell;
            min-height: 1px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            margin-left: 200px;
            margin-top: -10px;            
        }
```

---

```
.r-listbox 
{
  -ms-overflow-style:scrollbar;
  overflow:scroll;
  width: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: -10px; ``           
}
```

I have been added, but in IE 11 still can not display scroll.
[image]

Comment: Maybe you are using the touch version of IE11, so the scrollbars are hidden but they are activated.

Comment: can u share your html code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to write cross browser css for IE it should look like this :-

```
.r-listbox {
    -ms-overflow-style:scrollbar;
    overflow:scroll;
    width: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: -10px;            
}
```

you should have to take a look here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771902(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Since this could work, you are wrong in the `Cross-browser css` because it's a propietary definition, not a crossbrowser solution. The problem here seems to be that I'm talking in the main post in comments, that IE11 is running in touch mode.

Comment: I have added “-ms-overflow-style:scrollbar;” but it is still not display scroll bat.